# Linear Algebra: Proof of linear independence, given a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations, independence

Let $E$ be a vector space and $φ : E → E$ be a linear map. Let $x, y ∈ E$ \ $\{0\}$ and $λ, μ ∈ F$ such that $φ(x) = λx$ and $φ(y) = μy$. Prove that if $λ \neq μ$ then $\{x, y\}$ is linearly independent.

---

So, I typically know how to prove linear independence (Assume otherwise, set the linear combination of the elements equal to 0, with not all of the scales being 0). But when I do this with this question I do not get very far. My failed proof is below.

PF:
Suppose $\{x, y\}$ are not linearly independent. So, for some scalers $s, t \in \mathbb{F}$, not all zero, $sx+ty=0$.

$\iff$ $\phi(sx+ty)=\phi(0) = 0$

$\iff$ $\phi (sx)+\phi (ty) = s \phi(x) + t \phi (y)$

$\iff s(\lambda x) + t (\mu y)$.

So, $0 = s(\lambda x) + t (\mu y)$ $\iff$ $-\lambda xs = \mu ty$.

$x \neq 0 \neq y$.

$s,t$ are both non-zero, because if one was $0$, then the other would have to be zero because of $sx+ty=0$, from the beginning.

And I am having trouble moving on from here. Recommendations? Am I going about this right?

Comment: You don't need to use both $s$ and $t$. As $\mathbb F$ is a field, you can simply use one scalar to caracterise if they are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\{x,y\}$ is not linearly independent.  Then there exists an $\alpha\in F$ such that $x=\alpha y$.

Then $$\lambda x = \varphi(x) = \varphi(\alpha y) = \alpha\varphi(y) = \alpha\mu y = \mu(\alpha y) = \mu x$$  Hence $\lambda=\mu$.  Contradiction.